# Get updated object after mapping by lambda expression

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects as following,

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(
                Student.builder().id(1L).name("Joe").build(),
                Student.builder().id(2L).name("Jan").build()
        )
);
```

I want to update one of these objects and I have the following implementation

```
return findAll().stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getId() == studentId)
            .map(s -> students.set(students.indexOf(s), Student.builder().id(s.getId()).name(studentPayload.getName()).build()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new StudentNotFoundException(String.format("Student with id [%d] not found", studentId)));
```

This returns an object which satisfied with the condition based on `filter`. Unfortunately this is an **not-up-to-date object**!

How can I get the updated object after mapping?

Comment: Seems like complexity resulting from efforts to make it a one-liner. This problem will pretty much go away if you filtered to find your object, then updated it as separate statements... and the resulting code would be more readable!

Comment: Does the type of your built `Student` object override `equals()` and `hashCode()`?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you're dealing with at most one element, don't use streams.

Comment: Hi @AmalK, yes it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `set` method of a `List` would return the **PREVIOUS** element at that position and not the newly created one. [Refer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-)

Assuming that your id value is unique, I don't think it is neat to use `map` and then `findFirst` even though you could achieve the desired result.

Instead use `findFirst` and get the element and then then update the details as a second step.

```java
Student sOne = findAll().stream()
                      .filter(s -> s.getId() == studentId)
                      .findFirst()
                      .orElseThrow(() -> new StudentNotFoundException(String.format("Student with id [%d] not found", studentId)));
    
Student sTwo = students.get(students.indexOf(sOne));
if(sTwo!=null) {
    sTwo.setName(studentPayload.getName());
}

return sTwo;
```

If you still want to do it in single line, then use:

```
map(s -> {
    Student stu = students.get(students.indexOf(s));
    stu.setName(studentPayload.getName());
    return stu;
}
```

Comment: As I understand the code in the question, it's updating both the matching object from the `findAll()` list *and* the matching object from `students`. I think this code would only update the former.

Comment: @ernest_k Yeah I somehow missed the `findAll` part (I have updated my answer). But only the object from `students` is updated right?

Comment: Ah you're right. Only `students` is updated.